# Flask can't get data from sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I can't understand why I can't get data from SQLAlchemy in the Flask functions and templates. Here is code:
1. main.py

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

    from flask import Flask, jsonify, request, g, render_template as render
    from models import *
    from settings import *
    from flask_httpauth import HTTPBasicAuth


    ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = set(EXTENSIONS)
    auth = HTTPBasicAuth()

    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER


    @app.route('/')
    def home_page():
        brands = [item.serialize for item in session.query(Category).all()]
        items = []
        title = ''
        print brands
        return render('catalog/index.html', brands=brands, cars=items, titlr=title)


    if __name__ == '__main__':
        app.debug = True
        app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

2. models.py:

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/env python
   # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

   from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, ForeignKey, DateTime
   from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
   from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, sessionmaker
   from sqlalchemy import create_engine
   from passlib.apps import custom_app_context as pwd_context
   from itsdangerous import TimedJSONWebSignatureSerializer as Serializer
   from itsdangerous import BadSignature, SignatureExpired
   from data_control import get_unique_str


   Base = declarative_base()  # initialisation the database
   secret_key = get_unique_str(32)  # create secret_key

   # create session
   engine = create_engine('sqlite:///catalog.db')
   Base.metadata.bind = engine
   DBSession = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
   session = DBSession()


   # TODO: User model
   class User(Base):
       __tablename__ = 'user'
       id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
       username = Column(String(32), index=True)
       picture = Column(String(250), default='/img/no-img.png')
       first_name = Column(String(25), default=None)
       last_name = Column(String(25), default=None)
       email = Column(String(40))
       password_hash = Column(String(64))
       status = Column(String(10), default='user')

       def hash_password(self, password):
           """
           hash password

           :param password:
           :return void:
           """
           self.password_hash = pwd_context.encrypt(password)

       def verify_password(self, password):
           """
           Password verification

           :param password:
           :return bool:
           """
           return pwd_context.verify(password, self.password_hash)

       @property
       def get_full_name(self):
           """
           Return full name (first and last name)

           :return string:
           """
           return "%s %s" % (self.first_name, self.last_name)

       def generate_auth_token(self, expiration=3600):
           """
           Generate authentication token

           :param expiration:
           :return string: (token)
           """
           s = Serializer(secret_key, expires_in=expiration)
           return s.dumps({'uid': self.id})

       @staticmethod
       def verify_auth_token(token):
           """
           Try to load token, success return user id false return None

           :param token:
           :return mix:
           """
           s = Serializer(secret_key)
           try:
               data = s.loads(token)
           except SignatureExpired:
               # Valid Token, but expired
               return None
           except BadSignature:
               # Invalid Token
               return None
           uid = data['uid']
           return uid

       @property
       def serialize(self):
           """
           Return user data

           :return dict:
           """
           return {
               'id': self.id,
               'username': self.username,
               'picture': self.picture,
               'first_name': self.first_name,
               'last_name': self.last_name,
               'email': self.email,
               'status': self.status
           }


   # TODO: Image model
   class Image(Base):
       __tablename__ = 'image'
       id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
       product = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
       url = Column(String(250))

       @property
       def serialize(self):
           """
           Return user data

           :return dict:
           """
           return {
               'id': self.id,
               'url': self.url
           }


   # TODO: Category model
   class Category(Base):
       __tablename__ = 'category'
       id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
       name = Column(String(30))

       @property
       def serialize(self):
           """
           Return user data

           :return dict:
           """
           return {
               'id': self.id,
               'name': self.name
           }


   # TODO: Catalog model
   class Catalog(Base):
       __tablename__ = 'catalog'
       id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
       model = Column(String(30))
       title = Column(String(250))
       description = Column(String(250))
       category = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("category.id"), nullable=False)
       price = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
       author = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("user.id"), nullable=False)

       def get_author(self):
           """
           Return product`s author

           :return object:
           """
           return session.query(User).filter_by(id=self.author).one().serialize

       def get_images(self):
           """
           Prepare list of images for JSON

           :return list:
           """
           images = session.query(Image).filter_by(product=self.id).all()
           return [img.serialize for img in images]

       def get_category(self):
           """
           Return category

           :return object:
           """
           category = session.query(Category).filter_by(id=self.category).first()
           return category.serialize

       @property
       def serialize(self):
           """
           Return user data

           :return dict:
           """
           return {
               'id': self.id,
               'model': self.model,
               'title': self.title,
               'description': self.description,
               'brand': self.get_category(),
               'price': self.price,
               'images': self.get_images(),
               'author': self.get_author(),
           }


   Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
   ```

   in template:

   ```
   {% extends 'base.html' %}

   {% block title %}{{ title }}{% endblock %}

   {% block content %}

   <div class="row">
   {{ brands }}
   {% for item in brands %}
     <div>{{ item.name }}</div>
   {% endfor %}
   {% for car in cars %}
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4">
     <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4 mb-5">
       <span class="tumbl-image" data-ng-click="main.showDescription()"
             image-bg="{{ car.images[0].url }}">
         <div class="hide description">{{ car.description }}</div>
       </span>
       <div class="pt-2 text-center" id="title-link">
         <a href="/car/{{ car.id }}">{{ car.title }}</a>
       </div>
       <div class="pt-2">
         <span data-ng-click="main.sendEmail(item.author.email)" class="mail-to">
           <i class="fa fa-envelope-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
         </span>
         <a href="/profile/{{ car.author.id }}">{{ car.author.first_name }} {{ item.author.last_name }}</a>
       </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   {% endfor %}
   </div>
   {% endblock %}
   ```

if I run app and go to localhost:5000 I see []

in terminal:

```
* Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
* Restarting with stat
* Debugger is active!
* Debugger PIN: 342-567-684
```

[]
   127.0.0.1 - - [11/Dec/2017 15:34:00] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -

but if I run python console:

```
    PyDev console: starting.
    import sys; print('Python %s on %s' % (sys.version, sys.platform))
    sys.path.extend(['/path/to/catalog'])
    Python 2.7.10 (default, Jul 15 2017, 17:16:57) 
    [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.31)] on darwin
    >>> from main import *
    >>> brands = [item.serialize for item in session.query(Category).all()]
    >>> print brands
    [{'id': 1, 'name': u'BMW'}, {'id': 2, 'name': u'Ford'}, {'id': 3, 'name': u'Nissan'}, {'id': 4, 'name': u'Toyota'}, {'id': 5, 'name': u'Dodge'}, {'id': 6, 'name': u'Audi'}, {'id': 7, 'name': u'Jeep'}, {'id': 8, 'name': u'Mazda'}, {'id': 9, 'name': u'Chevrolet'}]
```

Would someone please tell me why flask doesn't output data? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I spent two days to find solution, but problem was with PyCharm. I don't know why, but for some reason if i try to run the app in PyCharm SQLAlchemy stops working. If I run the app in terminal, it works well.

P.S. I hope this helps someone.